# How to find same values from different cell in Excel file using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Range_Number_Phone;
Range_Number_Phone = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Find("Phone");

This code finds first values only.it can't find another word.How is it possible?Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Free Spire.XLS dll from NuGet Package Manager we can find same values from a different cell.

```
        Spire.Xls.Workbook workbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\\input.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);

        //find and highlight excel data
        Spire.Xls.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        foreach (CellRange range in sheet.FindAllString("Customer PO Number", false, false))
        {
            range.Style.Color = Color.LawnGreen;
        }
        //save and launch the project
        workbook.SaveToFile("result.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("result.xlsx");
```